# Using Exchange Backup and Restore SDK from MSDN

Tags: sdk, backup, exchange-server

I was wondering how to use the new Exchange Backup and Restore SDK from MSDN.
Check it out here, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4979

The documentation says it contains example, but I don't find any ways to use it though.
Or does it contain only documentation?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: well, i figured it out. if any one needs it, look into the exchange documentation node in All Programs in Start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exchange documentation node in All Programs in Start menu